# I can't get my head around websockets (via socket.io and node.js)

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io, client-server

I'm new to websockets/socket.io/node.js.  I'm trying to write a card game app, but pretty much all the example tutorials I've found are creating chat applications.  So I'm struggling to get my head around the concepts and how they can be applied to my card game.

Keeping it simple, the card game will involve two players. The game involves moving cards around the table. Each player has to see the other player's moves as they happen (hence the need for constant connections).  But the opponents cards are concealed to the other.

So two people browse to the same table then click to sit (and play, when both seats are taken). Using

```
io.on("connection", function(sock){
      //socket events in here
});
```

am I creating the one socket ('io', or 'sock'?) that both clients and the server share, or is that two separate sockets (server/clientA and sever/clientB)?  I ask, because I'm struggling to understand what's happening when a message is emitted and/or broadcast.  If a client emits a message, is that message sent to both the server and the other client, or just the server?  And then, further does it also send the message to itself as well??  It seems as though that's the logic... or what is the purpose of the 'broadcast' method?

From a functional perspective, I need the server to send different messages to each player.  So it's not like a chatroom where the server sends the chat to everyone. But if it's one socket that the three of us share (clients and server), how do I manage who sees what?  I've read about namespaces, but I'm struggling to work out how that could be used.  And if it's two separate sockets, then I can more easily imagine sending different data to the separate clients. But how is that implemented - is that two 'io' objects, or two 'sock' objects?

Finally, I've got no idea if this is the sort of long-winded question that is accepted here, so if it's not, can someone direct me to a forum that discussions can occur?  Cheers!

(in case it matters I'm also using Expressjs as the server).

Edit to add:
Part of my confusion is regarding the difference between 'io' and 'sock'.  This code eg from the socket.io page is a good example of methods being applied to either of them:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.emit('request', /* */); // emit an event to the socket
  io.emit('broadcast', /* */); // emit an event to all connected sockets
  socket.on('reply', function(){ /* */ }); // listen to the event
});
```

Comment: I can advice you to split your problem into set of small issues. And move on by small steps.

Comment: The steps are fine.  It's the overall big picture that escapes me.  I don't understand what exactly is going on when a 'connection' is made involving multiple parties.  I'd test it myself, but I'm not sure that will work from the same client (but different browsers), will it?

Comment: In connection this `sock` - is your socket object between user and server. You can play around it to achieve your result. Also have a look at rooms.

Comment: I've read about rooms, but I can't translate that out of the chatroom paradigm.  Regarding `sock`, as I mentioned, is that a connection shared by one client and the server, or all clients and the server?  So if the server (or the client) emits on that connection, who receives?

Comment: it's connection about 1 client and server

Comment: Ok, so how is emitting/broadcasting done to both clients?  What is the shared object between the server and the two clients?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153126/discussion-between-lazyexpert-and-erv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSocket server side listens for incoming socket connections from clients.

Each client upon connection opens its own socket between him and server. The server is the one that keeps track of all clients.

So once client emits the message server is listening for, the server can do with that message whatever. The message itself can contain information about who is the recipient of that message.

The server can pass the message to everyone or broadcast it to specific user or users based on information your client has sent you or some other logic.
For a card game:

The server listens for incoming connections. Once two clients are connected both of them should emit game ID in which they want to participate. The server can join their sockets in one game(Room) and all of the communication between those two clients can continue in that room. Each time one of the clients passes data to the server, that data should contain info about the recipient.

Here is one simple example that could maybe get you going:
Client side

```
// set-up a connection between the client and the server
var socket = io.connect();
// get some game identifier
var game = "thebestgameever";
socket.on('connect', function() {
 // Let server know which game you want to play
 socket.emit('game', game);
});
function makeAMove(move)
{
socket.emit('madeAMove', {move:move, game:game});
}

socket.on('move', function(data) {
  console.log('Player made a move', data);
 });
```

Server side

```
io = socketio.listen(server);
 //listen for new connections from clients
 io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
// if client joined game get his socket assigned to the game
socket.on('game', function(game) {
    socket.join(game);
});
socket.on('madeAMove', function(data){
  let game = data.game;
  let move = data.move;
  io.sockets.in(game).emit('move', move);
});
})
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Give me a little time to absorb that. In the meantime, `.join` that's 'rooms' isn't it? Do I need to use rooms, though? I'm guessing it must be necessary to separate out each game table running on the server? Just finally, clients can only talk to server, not each other, right?  And `.emit`, wouldn't the emitter just get caught in an infinite loop of replying to its own messages? Basically that's what I was getting at with the question about the difference between 'emit' and 'broadcast'.

Comment: Emit sends a message to everyone who is listening. Adding broadcast means that server sends a message to everyone who is listening excluding the one socket that sent a message. So you could use io.sockets.in(game).emit('move', move) to send message to everyone in the game(including socket that sent message in the first place) or  socket.broadcast.to(game).emit('move', move) and send message to all sockets excluding the one that message originated from. Use broadcast as a way to prevent socket receiving the message it sent.

Comment: And yes, rooms would be a convenient way to separate game tables, plus that gives you an opportunity to make multi player games one day.

Comment: I want to start testing some of these ideas, but I first need to generate a unique tableID. Can you advise me how to do that? I can't work out how to dynamically alter the index.html (the sole table, at the moment) before it is sent to the client on connection.  Is it possible to insert a tableID into a static html file before it is served up?

Comment: For testing purposes you can use any random hardcoded gameID. For future development I would consider using players Id's in some combination . For example player A chooses to start a game with player B. That game would have id AB, but that is really up to you

Comment: Ok. cheers.  For the time being, I've done it via the opened socket.  As soon as the page loads, the server js sends the client js a table ID and it inserts it into the page.